# How can I attach a function to an onClick event using Angel/Jael?

Tags: dart

I need to update table results when a "Next" button is pressed using Angel and Jael.

Currently, this is the code I have:

`<button class="next" type="button" onclick="{{ nextPage }}">Next Page</button>`

```
    var regbattles = Pagination(await getUnrankedBattles(), 30);
    updatePage() {
      regbattles.nextPage();
    }
    app.get('/', (req, res) async {
      await res.render('index', {'regbattles': regbattles.currentItems, 'nextPage': updatePage});
    });
```

I've tried adding `()` to `nextPage` in the onclick function, and it did not work. I can't seem to find any tutorials for this. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Jael is solely an HTML-generating engine, and is stateless, so the renderer doesn't have any connection to JavaScript. So you can't pass a Dart function to the browser, and have it called. You'll need to send a request to the server from JavaScript.

I'm not familiar with any templating engine that allows that, though.